# jquery javascript obtain image sources with conditions from page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, conditional-statements

I have a script that will get images from page, but how do I do it with conditions? Such as width/height size?

Right now I have this

```
(function(){

    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

}());
```

So I get all the tags that has img and it gets its sources, but how would i get images with conditions?

Is there a certain attribute I can get? Am I supposed to use if else situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use attributes and make condition based on them.

For instance, imgs[i].style.width == "75px" or $(imgs[i]).width() == 75

```
 (function(){

        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var imgSrcs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
           if($(imgs[i]).width() == 75)
               imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);    
        }

    }());
```

Comment: and what if style='width: auto' but it actually has 75px? Also, `imgs[i].style.width` will return '##px' and you cannot compare with an int

Comment: I think you will get 75px instead of auto. Update my answer for px, you can use jquery it will return width without px

Comment: I tried the jquery syntax, and deleted the `.width` from `.width().width` and it got images. was this a typo you have?

Comment: Updated my answer there was a typing mistake, sorry about that. @andrewliu

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgSrcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   if(imgs[i].style.clientWidth == 75)
       imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
}

}());
```

Comment: what is the difference between clientWidth and regular width?